# php import remote libraries to run them locally

Tags: php, local, remote-server

Being as much direct as I can... does exists a way/tool to share/export PHP libraries remotely available to let them executed locally?

Let me dedetail a little bit better the need that I have:

I'm the web developper/administrator for some subdomains available on my company and each of them shares local data and it's installed and configured on a separate host

```
http://division-A.company.com    (running on division-A.company.com)
http://division-B.company.com    (running on division-B.company.com)
http://division-Z.company.com    (running on division-C.company.com)
```

The different host are

1. configured differently,
2. shows different information for different pourpouse
3. but all of them shares the same version of Apache & PHP (5.4.7)

Considering that the 3 different web host are maintained by me... do I have a chance to share with them some common php libraries.

I mean, for example:

Having a function available on [ host-A.company.com ]

```
webuser@host-A.company.com: /httpdocs/lib/helloworld.php
```

.

```
<?php
function HelloWorld() {
     echo "You are on host " $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "\n";
     return(true);
}
?>
```

Can (in some way) import it on another host?

```
webuser@host-B.company.com: /httpdocs/lib/import_remote.php
```

.

```
<?php
   include_once("http://division-A.company.com/lib/import_remote.php");
?>
```

But this approach (and it's more than clear why) does not work properly as the code is executed on remote host and not local one whereas my goal is to have a function that provide me a way to

- have the function remotely available
- but run it locally

Comment: I think your best bet is to mount an SSH path and use it as though it were a local one (using something like SSHFS https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) .

Comment: Consider that *every single request* to your PHP app will require this "remote include". That's a prohibitive performance bottleneck. Just copy the file to the actual machine and use deployment automation to manage the file.

Comment: I'm not saying you should do what I've suggested. I'm just saying it's theoretically possible. The load overhead (as @deceze points out) is not the only consideration here. First of all you need to allow direct access to your site source code remotely which is a security issue since if not done correctly may expose your source-code to the world. At the same time when one of your sites goes down, all other dependent sites go down as well.

Comment: The copy from "master functions repository" to local is an option I'm going to evalute. The matter is that I would also have to implement an "automatic replica system" as the functions repository is growing up (not every day but from project to project) as most of function that I write for a specific project may be usefull even of other purpouse (on different host). Anyway thank you all for spending time thinking about my need.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to extract your library into separate repository, and include it as a dependency to all your sites via composer.

Comment: That's the unique option I've found too. The matter is that my goal is to have an unique "common" library that may grow up or be extended and it should be automatically available on any other site. If I would not find any (safe) workaround, I'll implement a replica system to deploy modification from a "master copy" to any host that has to used it.

Comment: I wouldn't call "automatically available" a safest option. Changes required for one of the sites may cause regression for others, especially when library grows up. It is way much safer to update library, test for regression, and deploy one site at a time, unless you have some specific requirements.